# stl std::generate c++, how to write the function call

Tags: c++, stl

So I have a programming assignment where they supply us with the header file which contains:

```
class SEQ{
private:
...// stuff
public:
...//constructor 
string operator ( ) ( ) {
    string tmp = id; int i = nd - 1;
    if ( id [ i ] < '9' ) id [ i ]++;
    else {
        id [ i ] = '1'; bool flag = true;
        for ( i--; i >= 0 && flag; i-- )
            if ( id [ i ] < 'Z' ) { id [ i ]++; flag = false; }
            else id [ i ] = 'A';
    } 
    return tmp;
}
}
```

I am supposed to use this with std::generate on an std::vector. However, the function never gets called. I have tried writing it these ways:

```
vector<string> v; 
for (int i = v.size(); i < in.N; i++) v.push_back("");

generate(v.begin(), v.end(), SEQ); // compiler error
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), SEQ()); // no error but does nothing

SEQ seq; // declare an instance
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), seq); // no error but does nothing
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), seq()); // compiler error algorithm line 1527 does not evaluate to a function that takes 0 arguments
```

I am assuming the header file they gave me does not contain any errors. How am I supposed to write this so that the function gets called?

Comment: How is `v` declared?

Comment: I've tried two ways. First, I just did a default constructor and increased it's capacity to the desired size. Then I thought maybe end() still pointed to begin(), so deleted the capacity increase and opted for push_back()

Comment: Can you show exactly what you have in the code above?

Comment: vector<string> tags; for (int i = tags.size(); i < in.N; i++) tags.push_back(""); generate(tags.begin(), tags.begin(), /* various */);

Comment: `std::vector<std::string> v(desired_size);` should fix your issue.

Comment: @Jarod42, I believe that just sets the capacity of the vector, which I have done before by using tags.reserve(desired_size).

Comment: The issue here is you still have a empty vector.  Jarod42's comment will fix your problem.

Comment: @crmsnfatalis No, `std::vector<std::string> v(desired_size);` fills the vector with `desired_size` empty strings.  `tags.reserve(desired_size)` just allocates memory but creates no objects.

Comment: I found the problem, it was a stupid typing error. I'm not sure how it got that way because I didn't type it that way originally, but I'm using begin() for the beginning and then end (no call to end())

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I didn't know the constructor behaved in that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`generate` takes a function pointer or a reference to an instance of a functor. The following two calls are correct. They are no-ops if the vector is empty.

```
// pass a default-constructed temporary instance
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), SEQ{});
// pass a named instance
SEQ seq;
generate(v.begin(), v.end(), seq);
```

The following works:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    std::vector<size_t> v(10);
    auto seq = [a = 0]() mutable { return a++; };
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), seq);
    assert(v.begin() != v.end());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
       assert(v[i] == i);
}
```